# Rewrite Magento Session last URL

Tags: magento, url, session, url-rewriting, cart

How can i get the rewrite url of the `$_SESSION['core']['last_url']?`
Cause `$_SESSION['core']['last_url']` is returning like this

catalog/product/view/id/166/category/8

and what i need is this

electronics/cell-phones/htc-touch-diamond.html

Help Please...

Answer (score 2):

Last visited URL is set in `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::postDispatch()` method. You can find there this line

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setLastUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true)));
```

`Mage::getUrl()` is responsible for creating an URL, that's why you don't get a rewrite here. You could override this method and check if this is a category or product page and based on that assign different URL, e.g.:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true));
if (Mage::registry('current_product') || Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl() . substr($this->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo(), 1);
}
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setLastUrl($url);
```